# Log prints tcp connection and others in xcode 8

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8, mixpanel

Finally, i migrated my code to swift 3 and now i am able to compile and run the code but i see bunch of log data like shown below. I guess this are from mixpanel. So from where and why this logs are there i dont know. And is this data relevant to keep while logging?

```
2016-10-13 16:58:49.791443[69008:344186] [] tcp_connection_start 1 starting
2016-10-13 16:58:49.791741[69008:344186] [] nw_connection_create creating connection to api.mixpanel.com:443
2016-10-13 16:58:49.792092[69008:344186] [] tcp_connection_start starting tc_nwconn=0x7fae49d06750
2016-10-13 16:58:49.792444[69008:344344] [] __nw_connection_start_block_invoke 1 starting
2016-10-13 16:58:49.792767[69008:344344] [] nw_endpoint_handler_start [1 api.mixpanel.com:443 initial path (null)]
```

Comment: Set an environment variable 'OS_ACTIVITY_MODE' = 'disable' in your debug scheme. @Parth Adroja

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

1- From Xcode menu open: Product > Scheme > Edit Scheme

2- On your Environment Variables set `OS_ACTIVITY_MODE = disable`

[image]

It should work..

Cheers!

Comment: Thnx it worked...

Comment: This disables all logs. Bad idea